# SD Card path change resetting in Android Studio AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdcard, android-virtual-device

I want to change the SD card setting for my emulator in `External File` from an old image that doesn't exist anymore, to a new image.

I created a new disk image using `./mksdcard -l mySdCard 1024M mySdCardFile.img`, which makes a new disk image called `mySdCardFile.img` with a size of 1GB, and a volume label `mySdCard`.

The disk image was in `/Users/[YOUR_USER_ID]/Library/Android/sdk/tools/`.

Then, I proceeded to setting `/Users/[YOUR_USER_ID]/Library/Android/sdk/tools/mySdCardFile.img` as the path for `External File`. I clicked finish. But, when I click on the emulator instance in the AVD manager, it keeps resetting to the old settings, that points to the old path which conveniently doesn't exist anymore. Restarting Studio, etc. doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After launching AVD manager, click the `down arrow` next to the target emulator, then click on `Show on Disk`.

Open `config.ini` and set the line `sdcard.path=/Users/[YOUR_USER_ID]/Library/Android/sdk/tools/mySdCardFile.img`.

Then, open `hardware-qemu.ini` and set the line `hw.sdCard.path = /Users/[YOUR_USER_ID]/Library/Android/sdk/tools/mySdCardFile.img`.

The AVD manager should reflect the change now.